# how to pass values from database to kartik checkbox list

Tags: yii2, checkboxlist, kartik-v

i have passed some values($list) fetched from database to yii2 default checkbox list and it is successfully showing the result

```
<?php $list=ArrayHelper::map(Questions::find()->all(),'id','question'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'dept_id')->checkboxList($list); ?>
```

how can i pass the same $list with kartik checkboxlist,shown below

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'dept_id')->widget(CheckboxX::classname($list), [
    'initInputType' => CheckboxX::INPUT_CHECKBOX,
    'autoLabel' => true
])->label(false); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This widget allows three checkbox states [1, 0 and null]
You could use [Yii2: ActiveField CheckboxList](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkboxList()-detail) Instead. This way you can specify *n options to in form of checkboxes.